# How to Create a New Excel file from Existing Template using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp.net, i want to create a new Excel spreadsheet based on an existing template file and populate it with data from a stored procedure.
i've tried using EPPlus but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm sure this question has been asked a few hundred times already..)

Here's the C# / VB.Net solution I came up with.

[Export to Excel](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

It's completely free to download, all source code is given.

It doesn't use an existing template, but it's really easy to use.  Just one line of code, you just pass it a `DataSet`, `DataTable` or `List<>` and it'll use OpenXML to create a real Excel file for you.

```
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(myDataSet, myExcelPathFilename);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, appreciate your help, but I've to use the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    public string Export(int entidadeID, int ccID, int paisID, bool mercApts)
 {
    string arquivo = "templateFile.xlsx";
//Template file is
string caminho = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/site/premissas/");
//New file will be for download
string _caminho = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/site/premissas/temp/");

    string _arquivo = "newname.xlsx";
    File.Copy(caminho + arquivo, _caminho + _arquivo);
    File.SetAttributes(_caminho + _arquivo, FileAttributes.Normal);

    string excelConnectString = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _caminho + _arquivo + @";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No'";
    //string excelConnectString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source = " + _caminho + _arquivo +@";" + "Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=No'";
    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter objDatAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();



    #region Fill Sheet
    string _nomePlanilha = "Plan1$";



    cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + _nomePlanilha + "]", objConn);
    objDatAdap.SelectCommand = cmd;
    objDatAdap.Fill(ds);
    objConn.Open();



    try
    {
   //F1, F2... are the columns in Excel, you can see it on ds DataSet filled above
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update [" + _nomePlanilha + "] set F4 = '" + your values + @"' where F2 = 'Value to compare'", objConn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch { }

}
```